# Abort fetch request in React Native

Tags: react-native, redux, fetch, expo

I have a React-Native App with a Redux Store. I have a fetch request and want to set a timeout if the fetch request gets to long and show an error message.

My question: How is it possible to set a timeout and abort the request? Because otherwise the request could be successful after the error message pops up and the response and the successful message is shown.

In RN 0.60 there is the AbortController, but how to use it with a redux store? Or is there another way with a boolean flag? The Redux Docs says:

> One way to do this is to create a function that you return from your
>   action creators. Then, only fire the "success" action as long as that
>   function is not called.

Do you have an example for that?

I can't show the whole code, but I try to explain.

My action has this method:

```
export function fetchData(type, id) {
 return (dispatch, state) => {
  return fetch(APIURL, {
   method: 'GET',
   headers: headers
  })
  .then /*handle Response and response errors */
 }
}
```

And I call the function in my component:

```
<Dialog
 action={async => 
{async () => {
  try {
    await this.props.fetchMyData();
    await openUrlInBrowser(URL);
  } catch (e) {
    this.showError();
  }
}}>

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: ThunkDispatch){
 fetchMyData: () => {
  return dispatch(fetchData("data"));
 }
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/benestudio/fetch/tree/feature/timeout

- > npm install whatwg-fetch-timeout --save

and add timeout to request:

```
export function fetchData(type, id) {
 return (dispatch, state) => {
  return fetch(APIURL, {
   method: 'GET',
   headers: headers,
   timeout: 500, /* milisecond */
  })
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. But the timeout option seems to change nothing on my fetch. The request is successfull, and I see the response Message. :/

Comment: it's timeout just help when your request not successfull ( backend server not repsonse anything  to client ).

Comment: I don't understand what you need timeout in your case ? can you give example

Comment: Yes of course. I fetch Data and get the Data Shown in an PDF, which is open in an browser. If this is successful in the app a success pop up is shown. If the fecthing Data durates too long, I want the the fetch is abort and the success message and the PDF isn't shown but an timeout error message instead. Thank you!